# multi graphs datas in zend framework

Tags: zend-framework, open-flash-chart

I'm trying to place multiple graphs in a page to form a dashboard.

I found the way to do that with placing the graphs source code directly in the controller and then display the graphs in the view, but I know it s not 'Clean' to do that especially with mvc.

Do you have an idea how to place my graph codes separately in a model class (as different functions I guess) and get the graphs data results from that model to the controller and then place the graphs in the view?

This is what I have done for 2 graphs (have many more that why I have to find a way to separate the source codes so wont have to change every parameter to be unique in the code:

contoller

```
  class stjpgController extends Oft_Controller_Action {

  public function init(){
  require_once 'Ofc/ofc_line_base.php';
  require_once 'Ofc/open-flash-chart.php';
  require_once 'Ofc/ofc_line_dot.php';
  require_once 'Ofc/ofc_line_hollow.php';

  }

public function graphAction(){
    $view = $this->view;
    $dateInBetween = array();
    $SmsSum = array();
    $smsSumGraph = array();
    $y_axis_values = array();
    $x_axis_values = array();


    $queryparse = oci_parse($conn, $query);
    oci_execute($queryparse);


    while ($row_date = oci_fetch_array($queryparse,
            OCI_ASSOC+OCI_RETURN_NULLS))
    {
         $y_axis_values[] = intval($row_date['SMSSUM']);
         $x_axis_values[] = $row_date['DATETO'];

    }

    $chart = new open_flash_chart();
    $y_axis = new y_axis();
    $x_axis = new x_axis();

    $default_dot = new line_dot();
    $tooltip = new tooltip();

    $x_labels = new x_axis_labels();
    $x_labels->set_labels($x_axis_values);
         $taille=sizeof($x_labels);
          $step=2;
          if ($taille>100) $step=4;
          if ($taille>200) $step=8;
          if ($taille>300) $step=12;
          if ($taille>400) $step=24;
    $x_labels->set_steps( $step );
    $x_labels->rotate('45');
    $x_axis->set_labels($x_labels);
    $x_axis->set_offset(false);
    $y_axis->set_range( 0, max($y_axis_values)+10, round( max($y_axis_values) / 4 ) );

    $chart->set_x_axis( $x_axis );
    $chart->add_y_axis( $y_axis );

    //LINE
    $line = new line();
    $line->set_values( $y_axis_values );       
    $line->set_halo_size( 0 );
    $line->set_width( 2 );
    $chart->add_element($line);

   $data = $chart->toPrettyString();

   $swfObject  = "swfobject.embedSWF(";
   $swfObject .= "'{$view->baseUrlMedia('ofc/open-flash-chart.swf')}', 'ofcchart',";
   $swfObject .= "'350', '300', '9.0.0', 'expressInstall.swf',";
   $swfObject .= "{'get-data':'get_data_ofc_chart'}, {'wmode': 'transparent'} );";

   $view->jquery()->addOnload("var data = {$data}");
   $view->jquery()->addOnload($swfObject);

   $view->dataChart = $data;

   //------------------------GRAPH 2----------------------------------- 
   $y_axis_values1 = array();
   $x_axis_values1 = array();
   $y_axis_values2 = array();
   $x_axis_values2 = array();

   $SuccRecMsgParse = oci_parse($conn,  $query1);

   oci_execute($SuccRecMsgParse);

   while ($row_date1 = oci_fetch_array($SuccRecMsgParse,
           OCI_ASSOC+OCI_RETURN_NULLS))
   {
       $y_axis_values1[] = intval($row_date1['SMSSUM']);
       $x_axis_values1[] = $row_date1['DATETO'];
   }

   $MOtotalIncParse = oci_parse($conn, $query2);

   oci_execute($MOtotalIncParse);

   while ($row_date2 = oci_fetch_array($MOtotalIncParse,
           OCI_ASSOC+OCI_RETURN_NULLS))
   {
       $y_axis_values2[] = intval($row_date2['SMSSUM']);
       $x_axis_values2[] = $row_date2['DATETO'];
   }




   $y_axis1 = new y_axis();
   $x_axis1 = new x_axis();

   $default_dot = new line_dot();
   $tooltip = new tooltip();

   $x_labels1 = new x_axis_labels();
   $x_labels1->set_labels($x_axis_values1);
   $taille=sizeof($x_labels1);
   $step=2;
   if ($taille>100) $step=4;
   if ($taille>200) $step=8;
   if ($taille>300) $step=12;
   if ($taille>400) $step=24;
   $x_labels1->set_steps( $step );
   $x_labels1->rotate('45');
   $x_axis1->set_labels($x_labels1);
   $x_axis1->set_offset(false);
   $y_axis1->set_range( 0, max($y_axis_values1)+10, round( max($y_axis_values1) / 4 ) );

   $default_dot = new line_dot();
   $default_dot->set_colour('#DFC329');

   $line_dot = new line();
   $line_dot->set_default_dot_style($default_dot);
   $line_dot->set_width( 4 );
   $line_dot->set_colour( '#DFC329' );
   $line_dot->set_values( $y_axis_values1 );
   $line_dot->set_key( "SuccRecMsg", 10 );
   $default_hollow_dot = new line_hollow();
   $default_hollow_dot->set_colour('#6363AC');

   $line_hollow = new line();
   $line_hollow->set_default_dot_style($default_hollow_dot);
   $line_hollow->set_width( 4 );
   $line_hollow->set_colour( '#6363AC' );
   $line_hollow->set_values( $y_axis_values2 );
   $line_hollow->set_key( "MOtotalInc", 10 );


   $chart1 =new open_flash_chart();
   $chart1->set_x_axis( $x_axis1 );
   $chart1->add_y_axis( $y_axis1 );
   $chart1->add_element($line_dot);
   $chart1->add_element($line_hollow);


   $data1 = $chart1->toPrettyString();

   $swfObject1  = "swfobject.embedSWF(";
   $swfObject1 .= "'{$view->baseUrlMedia('ofc/open-flash-chart.swf')}', 'ofcchart1',";
   $swfObject1 .= "'350', '300', '9.0.0', 'expressInstall.swf',";
   $swfObject1 .= "{'get-data':'get_data_ofc_chart1'}, {'wmode': 'transparent'} );";

   $view->jquery()->addOnload("var data1 = {$data1}");
   $view->jquery()->addOnload($swfObject1);

   $view->dataChart1 = $data1;
   }
}
```

View:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/json/json2.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/swfobject.js"></script>

<?= $this->headScript()->captureStart(); ?>
function get_data_ofc_chart(){
    return JSON.stringify(<?php echo $this->dataChart; ?>);

}

function get_data_ofc_chart1(){
    return JSON.stringify(<?php echo $this->dataChart1; ?>);

}

function findSWF(movieName) {
   if (navigator.appName.indexOf('Microsoft')!= -1) {
        //return window['ie_' + movieName];
        return document.getElementById('ie_'+movieName);
   } else {
        //return document[movieName];
        return document.getElementById(movieName);
   }
}

<?= $this->headScript()->captureEnd(); ?>

<div id="container">
<p></p>
<div id="ofc_chart"></div>
<div id="ofc_chart1"></div>
```